# Flutter - Recording Android system/application Or saving audio as mp3

Tags: android, flutter, dart, text-to-speech, audio-recording

hope you have a wonderful weekend . I am making a text to speech App that saves the speech as mp3 . I am using the "flutter_tts" package which plays audio upon giving it a text , how can i output the audio as mp3 or record it while it's playing.

```
FlutterTts flutterTts = FlutterTts();
flutterTts.speak(TextSample);
```

Answer (score 1):

FlutterTts now supports synthesizeToFile for Android.

```
synthesizeToFile(utterance, fileName)
```

So you can use it like this:

```
FlutterTts flutterTts = FlutterTts();
flutterTts.synthesizeToFile("hello world", "helloworld.wav")
```